# How to remove padding of 0 while using NSdateFormatter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Like if I am using the code.

```
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
 [df setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSString *log_date = [df stringFromDate:today];

 //Generate Log Current Time.
 [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
 NSString *log_currenttime = [[df stringFromDate:today] lowercaseString];

 NSLog(@"Log Date %@",log_date);
 NSLog(@"Log Current Time %@",log_currenttime);
```

My log shows me :

> Log Date 19.12.2011
>   Log Current Time 03:18pm

At least I can remove the Time Padding.

Comment: Means you want `03:18pm` to be like `3:18pm`?

Comment: Have you tried single letters as in: `[df setDateFormat:@"d.M.yyyy"];` (I don't have a test setup handy, so I'm posting as a comment).

Comment: Yes I want to display 3:18pm instead of 03:18.

Comment: The format is changed from "hh:mma" to "h:mma". Please see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your format from `hh:mma` to `h:mma`

```
//Generate Log Current Time.
[df setDateFormat:@"h:mma"]; // Changed from hh:mma to h:mma
NSString *log_currenttime=[[df stringFromDate:today] lowercaseString];

NSLog(@"Log Current Time %@",log_currenttime);
```

This will output

> Log Current Time 3:18pm

Comment: Thanks if we yse in date format as "h:mm" then it will show the contents without padding of zero....yes..

Comment: This works - but only for some languages / calendars. If added solution for all calendars around the world.

Answer (score 2):

As Eric wrote, use `h:mm` will fail for example on czech calendar.

Only way to do that is use system formatter.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
 [df setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
 [df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
 NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSString *log_date = [df stringFromDate:today];

 //Generate Log Current Time.
 [df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
 NSString *log_currenttime = [[df stringFromDate:today] lowercaseString];

 NSLog(@"Log Date %@",log_date);
 NSLog(@"Log Current Time %@",log_currenttime);
```

Comment: Ya, it is working right, but I can not understand what change you have made actually.

Comment: I have a basic understanding problem that, If we change just one line setTimeStyle, then how stringFromDate will give us, only time, not whole string that include date also,are u getting me. Otherwise working fine.

Comment: @ArpitParekh I changed [df setDateFormat:@"h:mma"]; to NSDateFormatters for time and date - its better than Format, because it uses system calendar format - not your own.. NSDateFormatter has two properties - date, and time. You wont date, so "NoStyle", you want time in short format - "ShortStyle". Read Apple Developers for more styles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Aadhira's answer is that if the user then switches to metric the `@h:mma` formatting will override it and make `23:00` look like `11:00pm`.

The padding comes from the users settings in `Settings`-->`General`-->`International`-->`Region Format`. For example if it is set to UK, you will get padding. If it is set to US you won't. You may want to respect this decision in your user interface.